# How to attach click event to AngularJS directive with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made **AngularJS directive**, that i load on my home page, also i have 
***JQuery*** file, where i call `alert('it works')` when `<p> Click </p>` element is clicked.
Here is the example.

```
/*
 * This is the directive
 */

outsource.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
            // Link
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'src/app/components/views/directive.html'
    };
});
```

directive.html file

```
<p id="clicked"> Click </p>
```

jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clicked").click(function() {
        alert('it works');
    });
});
```

This is just a simple question for my real problem. I've notices that  angular directive is loaded slower than my function that fires alert message. Because of that i have nothing selected by my selector `$("#clicked")`.

***How i should use angular directive with jquery? What is the right way to solve this jquery-angular issue beside using jqlite? ***

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `jQuery` when you have AngularJS.
You can use `ng-click` of AngularJS to bind `click` event on elements.

**HTML**

```
<p ng-click="clickHandler()">...</p>
```

**JavaScript**

In controller

```
$scope.clickHandler = function() {
    alert('clicked');
};
```

**EDIT**

Still you want to use `jQuery`(**Not Recommended**):

```
$(document).on('click', "#clicked", function() {
    alert('it works');
});
```

Comment: Ok i know how to use ng-click. But what if i have 20 elements where i must trigger alert message? How can i do that? With jquery i just select all elements, and attach event on them.

Comment: @VeskoVujovic No. Add `ng-click` to all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular `ng-click`. See this **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)**.

> The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an
>   element is clicked.

So why you want to use jQuery? AngularJs provide a best way to handle event for directives, use them.

Comment: The answer is, strictly speaking, correct; but talking about quality, Tushar's answer is way above. He says the same thing but _explains_ it and gives an actual answer.

Comment: I'm not even convinced this *does* answer the question. It is more of a comment